# Is there a "native dependencies" plugin for Leiningen?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I mean one that behaves like [this maven plugin](http://code.google.com/p/mavennatives/). Several libraries I use follow the conventions of that plugin, and while possible, it's rather annoying to manually scan the dependency graph for native dependencies and unpack them by hand.

Alternatively, if it doesn't exist I'd probably write it myself (doesn't seem so hard to do), but some pointers on doing so would be great - I suppose I'd have to use pomegranate here?

Answer (score 2):

Leiningen supports native dependencies out of the box just pack them according to the spec,

http://nakkaya.com/2010/04/05/managing-native-dependencies-with-leiningen/

Comment: According to _what_ spec? Note that I'm using lein2, and that post is from 2010. Also note this isn't doing what I asked for if it involves me running around repackaging natives (I didn't ask for a way to tell leiningen to use natives per-se, but rather for a way that uses that particular maven convention).

Comment: @Cubic , the convention explained in the post works for lein2. But I do not think a plugin for what you want exists.